# ClassCast Exception Error

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, classcastexception, android-bluetooth

When I am trying to use Application object for maintain bluetooth service in whole android app, My application throw me Classcast Exception. When I am trying to connect bluetooth Peripheral.

```
04-27 09:11:37.704    3289-3289/com.xemodex.bluetooth.xemodex E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xemodex.bluetooth.xemodex, PID: 3289
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xemodex.bluetooth.xemodex/com.xemodex.bluetooth.xemodex.DeviceControlActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.xemodex.bluetooth.xemodex.BluetoothController
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.xemodex.bluetooth.xemodex.BluetoothController
            at com.xemodex.bluetooth.xemodex.DeviceControlActivity.onCreate(DeviceControlActivity.java:135)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method
```

)

Comment: Show code where it crashes.

Comment: Please show some of your code. e.g. com.xemodex.bluetooth.xemodex.BluetoothController and your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Christopher Bluetooth Controller I place in answered So You  can read it very well.

Comment: @Christopher I posted my both files Mainfest and bluetoothController. If You can look at it Then It would be great. or If you have any idea how to maintain Bluettoh Connection in whole app. then its very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your BluetoothController as application in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:name=".BluetoothController"      <-- Here is the change
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
```